# Raise KeyError(key) from None in Project

Tags: python

I'm experimenting with the use of Huey as a cross platform task queue . I've found https://github.com/pjcunningham/flask-huey-example , which I've cloned and set up a virtualenv for using conda. following the readme I tried:

```
$ python run_app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_app.py", line 13, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "E:\ENVS\r3\hueytest1\app\__init__.py", line 12, in create_app
    _app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
  File "E:\miniconda2\envs\hueytest1\lib\os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'APP_SETTINGS'
```

I don't see APP_SETTINGS in the project . is this a Flask related env variable? How do I get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`APP_SETTINGS` it's not Flask variable, it's just for this Huey example.

Looking at the source [here](https://github.com/pjcunningham/flask-huey-example/blob/9516652b5a56e6423a5c006f68cf4031aa6ff030/app/__init__.py#L12), you need to supply enviromental variable APP_SETTINGS, that contains your configuration settings ([docs here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/#configuring-from-files)).

Example (from the documentation):

```
export APP_SETTINGS="yourapplication.default_settings"
```